# How to Paste Equation from Maxima to Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am using Maxima/wxMaxima in Windows to perform a calculation and I get a nicely formatted equation as output in wxMaxima. I can copy the Latex code of the equation and paste it into a math box in Lyx (Insert Math) but it is rendered as the raw Latex code instead of the formatted equation. How can I get the equation from wxMaxima to appear properly in Lyx?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I just tested with the code of an equation from Wikipedia and it rendered fine in LyX (version 2.1.3, Kubuntu). Can you show the code of one of these troublesome equations?

Comment: Can you also try Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX ? Note that this feature is relatively new, but it is in at least 2.1.3.

Comment: I also tested an equation from Wikipedia and it worked as expected. Here is an equation from Maxima:
\[\mathrm{fx}\left( x\right) :=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot x}}\cdot \mathrm{exp}\left( \frac{-x}{2}\right) \]

Comment: That also seems to work fine here, I get http://i.imgur.com/iS4WOJj.png

Comment: This is really weird. When I copy the equation from my comment above and paste it into Lyx it renders properly.

Comment: From Maxima (does not work): 
 \[\mathrm{fx}\left( x\right) :=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot x}}\cdot \mathrm{exp}\left( \frac{-x}{2}\right) \]
 

This works:
[\mathrm{fx}\left( x\right) :=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot x}}\cdot \mathrm{exp}\left( \frac{-x}{2}\right) ]

Comment: If you can look at the source for my comment above you will see that there is a leading \ on the Maxima code that is not showing in the comment.

Comment: @user1930565 You can use backticks for code. FOr example, `[\mathrm{fx` ... this way it will not be formatted.

Comment: @user1930565 Did you try my suggestion in comment 2?

Comment: We can't look at the source of comments. The code of questions/answers is available, but not comments. However, you can edit your question, and use code markup (select the code and press the button marked `{}`) to make sure that the code is printed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  equations you copy from Maxima, e.g.

```
\[\mathrm{fx}\left( x\right) :=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot x}}\cdot \mathrm{exp}\left( \frac{-x}{2}\right) \]
```

include opening and closing delimiters for  a math environment, in this case `\[` and `\]`. In LaTeX, they denote the start and end of a displayed, unnumbered equation. However, when you make an equation in LyX, you already have such delimiters, so you shouldn't add a second set.

Hence, if you don't copy the starting `\[` and closing `\]` it works fine.

The method mentioned by Scott Kosty in the comments also work fine: After copying the entire equation, including delimiters, do Edit --> Paste special --> Paste from LaTeX, *without* inserting a math environment first. Then LyX will read the delimiters from the code and insert the proper math environment.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to "Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste from LaTex" I get an error that says "Lyx: Cannot convert file." I am using Lyx 2.1.3. So, as a workaround I have to paste the Maxima equation in a text editor, remove the delimiters, and then paste it into Lyx. But that is much better than retyping the equation from scratch.

Comment: @user1930565 glad it is an improvement at least. But it is unfortunate the "Paste from LaTeX" does not work for you. Can you please make a bug for this at http://www.lyx.org/trac ? Also please post there whether you are able to import a .tex file (create a .tex file with a simple LaTeX code and see if you can successfully import it going to File > Import).